# How to find new x,y,z after applyMatrix in Processing?

Tags: matrix, 3d, processing

I have a model with joints that individual shapes rotate around. The model is translated to the center. The matrix applied with `applyMatrix()` is a rotation matrix based on a quaternion value so it can rotate around without gimbal lock.

But then I want to translate and rotate around a JOINT point, which uses an offset of the model, so I can find that point, because it's just `model.x/y/z + offset.x/y/z`. However, this doesn't take into consideration the rotation from `applyMatrix()`, but I want to be able to calculate where the Joint point `(x,y,z)` is at whatever rotation it's in.

```java
translate(width/2, height/2, 0);
applyMatrix(m[1][1],m[1][2],m[1][0],0,
            m[2][1],m[2][2],m[2][0],0,
            m[0][1],m[0][2],m[0][0],0,
            0,0,0,1);
pushMatrix();
// rotate around this joint point
translate(offsetX, offsetY, offsetZ);
// !!!!
// WHAT is the new x,y,z right here??
// !!!!
rotate(amt);
translate(-offsetX, -offsetY, -offsetZ);
shape(component)
popMatrix();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the **coordinates** section of [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/).

Specifically, it sounds like you're looking for the `screenX()` and `screenY()` functions. Or you could use the `modelX()` and `modelY()` functions to go the other way and convert your screen coordinates into model coordinates.

Comment: wow, processing surprises me with some of it's built-in functions. The modelX/Y/Z functions did the trick.

Comment: Is there also way a way to get a rotation matrix at a specific point among function calls to translate and rotate. Basically, it would just get the the rotation at a certain point avoiding the translations, so the same rotation could be applied to another object.

Comment: @karamazovbros Not that I know of, not out of the box anyway. I'd probably use trig for something like that.